# Python 2.7 ignore URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 113] No route to host>

Tags: python

I need help in python 2.7, with read data from local web server with command "urllib2.Request"
I have use code ( attached below ) and work fine, as long as the server is accessible (192.168.5.44). If the server is unavailable, then the code stops with an error

```
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 113] No route to host>
```

what should I add in the code so that in the event of an error, it will continue and add value of read ( example N/A or something..... )
I have couple of server like this, and all stops if one server is down.

My code:

```
    request = urllib2.Request("http://192.168.5.44")
    fip44 = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    time.sleep(1)
    sip44 = fip44.read()

    def beri44( sip44, first, last ):
        start = sip44.index( first ) + len( first )
        end = sip44.index( last, start )
        return sip44[start:end]

    jed = float (beri44( sip44, "[", "]" ))
    fjed = open("/var/www/html/Temp/jed.txt", "w")
    fjed.write(str(jed))      
    fjed.close()
    print"jed:", jed
```

Comment: Add a `try` / `except` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `try` and `except` block to avoid stopping the program due to any error, as follows:

```
try:
    request = urllib2.Request("http://192.168.5.44")
    fip44 = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    time.sleep(1)
    sip44 = fip44.read()

    def beri44( sip44, first, last ):
        start = sip44.index( first ) + len( first )
        end = sip44.index( last, start )
        return sip44[start:end]

    jed = float (beri44( sip44, "[", "]" ))
    fjed = open("/var/www/html/Temp/jed.txt", "w")
    fjed.write(str(jed))      
    fjed.close()
    print"jed:", jed
except:
    # Do whatever you want here in the case of an error occurred
    pass
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great, work! If i have 3 server I guess I have to add for each one separately "try and except" ? Shape and use is the same lika as for  " IF - ELSE " ?

Comment: If you are using `urllib2.Request` for each server, then yes: you'll need the `try` and `except` for each. Exactly, a similar behavior to `if/else`.